# Sencha EXT JS datagrid scrollbar specifically on column?

Tags: scrollbar, extjs, mouseover, gridpanel

We have a gridpanel with columns, that are displaying fine.  One column in particular, is a string that can be very large.  We want to add a scrollbar to this one column only to accommodate the large wall of text.

Can this be done with Sencha EXT JS?  Or if scrollbars can not be done, how about a mouse over to show the whole text in the column?

`var  secondTab = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {`

```
        columnWidth: 0.60,
        xtype: 'gridpanel',
        store: standardsResultsStore,
        autoheight: true,
        columns: [
            {
                id       :'standardName',
                text   : 'Standard Name',
                flex: 1,
                sortable : true,
                dataIndex: 'standard'
            },
            {
                text   : 'Description',
                flex    : 2,
                sortable : true,
                dataIndex: 'description_standard'
            }
        ]

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it with CSS, and added tdCls to the specific column

`.custom-column .x-grid-cell-inner { white-space:normal; } 
--- in tab tdCls: 'custom-column'`